# TLS 1.2 configuration for Hybris server

Tags: java, axis, tls1.2, sap-commerce-cloud

I created an Apache Axis 1.3 client to call payment gateway services and install it on hybris yempty extension. Now payment gateway support TLS 1.2 protocol to communicate Which is available on java 8. But I am using Hybris 5.3 which support only java 7. So I configured my client to use TLS 1.3 by setting Axisproperties.

AxisProperties.setProperty("org.apache.axis.components.net.SecureSocketFactory", TrustAllSSLSocketFactory.class.getName());

TrustAllSSLSocketFactory .java is my java class that is setting SSLContext to TLS 1.2.

This Solution is working on standalone java 7 and Tomcat 7. But not working on Hybris Server of Hybris 5.3.

Please provide some pointers for resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the workaround of this problem. Axis is not working well with hybris as AxisProperties resettled back by hybris taskexecutor running in background. Created Soap Client with wsimport tool and pass -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 to tomcat wrapper.conf.
I also set the system property to TLS 1.2. System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2"); Now TLS 1.2 negotiation working well.

Comment: Do you know how to use wsimport with TLSv1.2??